Dynamically generate Django .filter() query with various attrs and matching types
I use Django 1.6 and Python 2.7 and I need to generate queryset filter dynamically.
The basic thing I need is to use different fields (field1, field2, field3) in filter and use different type of matching (equals, startsfrom, endswith, contains).
Here is an example of possible combinations:
Mymodel.objects.filter(field1__strartswith=somevalue). 
# Or like this:
Mymodel.objects.filter(field2__endswith=somevalue). 
# Or like this:
Mymodel.objects.filter(field3=somevalue) 
# Or like this:
Mymodel.objects.filter(atrr3__contains=somevalue)


I've found this answer and it looks good but I believe there are some more "Django-like" ways to do it. I've also found this one with Q object.
But could I somehow import and pass to the queryset some objects of this types of matching?

You are using python 2 :(

Python 2.7 is not supported anymore... since January 1, 2020: https://pythonclock.org/

Whats wrong with the argument unpacking from your first link? thats the usual "django way"

There is nothing wrong with the method suggested in the first link. With or without the Q object you will most probably have to concatenate the field name (e.g. field1) with the operator (e.g. __startswith), or use a Lookup. The advantage of using Q objects is to be able to use logical operators such as OR (|), AND (&) etc if you have multiple filters.

@Sayse I don't no. Maybe it's just me, but from my perspective it has some flavor of exec(string) (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), isn't it?

The two links you share are the usual way to do this. It is not really clear what you mean by "could I somehow import and pass to the queryset some objects of this types of matching?" Are you perhaps talking about using lookup objects like: Book.objects.filter(LessThan(F("word_count"), 7500))? (Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/lookups/#lookup-reference)

@Paul - I wouldn't say so, you aren't giving someone free reign to execute anything they want, you still have to adhere to valid filters for your queryset

@Paul no, exec is very different from what happens there. A keyword argument passed via a dictionary is not really comparable to letting people exec random code. You can also have your own validation and only allow specific kwargs.

Also, you don't even need to think about django here, you're question boils down to  calling a python function with parameters constructed elsewhere, which is commonly done with the same unpacking strategy which you may have already used with more confidence

Ok, thanks everyone for your answers! I'll use approach from the firs link. :)
